# Office Document Icons still messed up after reassociation

Tags: windows-7, icons, microsoft-office-2010, file-association

My MS Office 2010 documents show up like this in Explorer:

[image]

They open fine, but I'd like to get the icon corrected.

- I have run a repair from Add/Remove programs.
- I have cleared the icon cache using the script provided in update 2 of [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/509467/263993).
- I have fixed the MS Office file associations from the command prompt using `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\winword.exe /r`
- I have checked the following registry key for a valid path to an icon `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\DefaultIcon`

  - Icon listed is a REG_SZ entry titled `(Default)` with the value `C:\Windows\Installer\{90140000-0012-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}\wordicon.exe,13`
  - The icon file specified in this registry entry exists within the listed directory

We have several systems around the office that are missing the file associations to MS Office. If I have not specified an "Open With" target for office documents on a particular system and I use the `winword.exe /r` command, the icons correct themselves upon next login. If I have already specified a target application, the icons stay the same.

How do I change these back?

Comment: Have you tried doing an Office Repair from Add/Remove Programs?

Comment: Ironically, I haven't tried that yet; want to run this remotely from the command prompt using PSEXEC - I think I can use setup.exe /repair to make it work... Let me give it a try.

Comment: @techie007 Didn't fix it! Crazy. I don't think anything is *wrong* as this point, it's just that the icon isn't associated correctly or something... very odd.

Comment: have you tried [clearing the users' icon caches](http://superuser.com/questions/499078/refresh-icon-cache-without-rebooting)?  Along that idea: Try switching the display settings to a lower bit-level for colour (like down to 16-bit "High color") apply it, check icons, and then switch back to 32-bit "True color" and check them again.  hopefully that'll cause that Icon Cache to refresh itself with the proper Icon.

Comment: Weird... The first time I changed the bit depth to 16 and then back to 32 the icons changed until I navigated away. When I navigated back they appeared as above. I rebooted and that had no effect. I tried switching again and the icons almost immediately switched back to what I depicted above. **Also** I have cleared the icon caches multiple times; to no avail. Is there an application that will allow me to navigate the IconCache db file and see what is inside of it?

Comment: I think perhaps there's something in the background messing with the icons/associations. Try deleting the IconCache.DB file and rebooting, but reboot into Safe Mode, and see if they "stick" as the right icons.  If so, use MSConfig to disable all non-MS utilities and services, and see if it continues to behave in Normal Mode.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't do it. I also tried manually removing the associations and rerunning the repair, but that didn't fix it. Even with the associations missing the icons were the same and files still opened in the appropriate applications. Shall we move this to chat? Don't want it to get too long. And thank you for the help :)

Comment: Something to do with the user, not the system. The `winword.exe /r` appears to fix the icon issue on the other user profiles with no associations. I logged in as a different user and the icons worked great. I'll track it down...